# What is an example of statically typed javascript in context to better unit testing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I'm new to testing but recently, I've been trying using angularJS and Jasmine.

With ES6 on the horizon, in comes new frameworks/languages like: atScript and google angular-dart.  Both which now support optional type javascript and they claim that it becomes easier for testing?

Question:
1.  Being a novice to testing could someone give me a practical example/usecase that would illustrate how statically typed javascript would be better for unit testing.  moreover an example where vanilla javascript unit test would fall short??

Lastly, if this isnt a stackoverflow question could we move it to the appropriate stack subdomain?

Comment: i don't know about better unit testing, but i can see how they enable _less_ unit testing because the runtime won't allow a lot of things that need to be explicitly tested today. read up on arguments why compiled code is "better" than interpreted code. Static typing can also make for better IDE auto-complete/suggestion features, cutting down on human error.

Comment: some of today's problems with human-written tests, stuff like typeof null==="object", potential concats in a+b/x, and typeof on new String("a") vs "a" may vanish or at least not be such a "gotcha".

Comment: Angular is built with a strong focus on testability (Dart and JS), this has nothing to do with type annotations. Besides that, see @dandavis' comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Type based assertions are possible. For example:

```
is(value : Dynamic, type : Dynamic, ?msg : String , ?pos : PosInfos)
```

> Asserts successfully when the 'value' parameter is of the of the passed type 'type'.

```
raises(method:Void -> Void, ?type:Class<Dynamic>, ?msgNotThrown : String , ?msgWrongType : String, ?pos : PosInfos)
```

> It is used to test an application that under certain circumstances must react throwing an error. This assert guarantees that the error is of the correct type (or Dynamic if none is specified).

This code:

```
enum Color { R, G, B }

function f1(x: Color | string) {
    if (typeof x === "number") {
        var y = x;
        var y: Color;
    }
    else {
        var z = x;
        var z: string;
    }
}

function f2(x: Color | string | string[]) {
    if (typeof x === "object") {
        var y = x;
        var y: string[];
    }
    if (typeof x === "number") {
        var z = x;
        var z: Color;
    }
    else {
        var w = x;
        var w: string | string[];
    }
    if (typeof x === "string") {
        var a = x;
        var a: string;
    }
    else {
        var b = x;
        var b: Color | string[];
    }
}
```

would need shims for the following:

- enum
- type hinting (`x: Color`)
- union types (`|`)

and this code:

```
class A {
    propA: number;
}

class B {
    propB: number;
}

class C extends A {
    propC: number;
}

declare function isB(p1): p1 is B;
declare function isC(p1): p1 is C;
declare function retC(x): C; 

declare function funA<T>(p1: (p1) => T): T;
declare function funB<T>(p1: (p1) => T, p2: any): p2 is T;
declare function funC<T>(p1: (p1) => p1 is T): T;
declare function funD<T>(p1: (p1) => p1 is T, p2: any): p2 is T;
declare function funE<T, U>(p1: (p1) => p1 is T, p2: U): T;

let a: A;
let test1: boolean = funA(isB);

if (funB(retC, a)) {
    a.propC;
}
let test2: B = funC(isB);
if (funD(isC, a)) {
    a.propC;
}
let test3: B = funE(isB, 1);
```

would need shims for the following:

- user-defined type guards (`p1 is B`)
- type casting of return values (`funA<T>(p1: (p1) => T): T`)

**References**

- [fponticelli/utest: cross-platform unit testing system for Haxe](https://github.com/fponticelli/utest)
- [Typescript infer return type from passed functions return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509076/typescript-infer-return-type-from-passed-functions-return-type)
- [What is the difference between ' : ' and ' => 'on functions in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400556/what-is-the-difference-between-and-on-functions-in-typescript)
- [Cappuccino - Testing with OJTest](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/learn/ojtest.html)
- [ECMAScript 6: New Features: Overview and Comparison](http://es6-features.org/)
- [TypeScript Github repo | typeGuardFunctionGenerics.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/cases/conformance/expressions/typeGuards/typeGuardFunctionGenerics.ts)
- [TypeScript Github repo | TypeGuardWithEnumUnion.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tests/cases/conformance/expressions/typeGuards/TypeGuardWithEnumUnion.ts)
- [List of reserved keywords · Issue #2536 · Microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2536)
- [Features That Will Matter in the Upcoming TypeScript 1.8 -- Visual Studio Magazine](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/03/28/features-in-upcoming-typescript-1-8.aspx)
- [Learn with Me - Typescript: A Study in Types - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1072357/Learn-with-Me-Typescript-A-Study-in-Types)
- [TypeScript 2.0: Even Better Data Typing and Class Discriminants -- Visual Studio Magazine](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/12/05/typescript-2-0-data-typing-class-discriminants.aspx)
- [Kicking TypeScript's Tires](http://blogs.adobe.com/bparadie/2012/10/21/kicking-typescipts-tires/)
- [TypeScript for ActionScript Developers](http://jessewarden.com/2012/10/typescript-for-actionscript-developers.html)
- [Hello World: How to set up Apache FlexJS to transpile ActionScript to JavaScript - NextGen ActionScript](https://nextgenactionscript.com/tutorials/hello-world-transpile-actionscript-apache-flexjs/)
- [Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Conversion-Guide: A guide for converting a simple JavaScript/React project to TypeScript. Contains both before an after code with the step-by-step process in the README below.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Conversion-Guide)