# Typescript infer return type from passed functions return type

Tags: function, generics, typescript

I might be trying to achieve the impossible but here goes.

I want to define a function ( function A ) which will return the same type as a new function passed into the parameter of function A.

e.g.

```
export function test<T> ( arg:Function ):T {
    return arg;
}

function a():string {
    return 'a';
}

function b():number {
    return 0;
}

let aVal:string = test(a);
let bVal:number = test(b);
```

Obviously this will allow me to strongly type my responses for some compile time errors.

Does anyone have any ideas or know if I'm just dreaming.

** Note: Code slapped together for demo **

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```js
function test<T>(arg: () => T): T {
    return arg();
}

function a(): string {
    return 'a';
}

function b(): number {
    return 0;
}

let aVal: string = test(a);
let bVal: number = test(b);
```

Instead of using the Function interface we defined arg as a function that takes no arguments and returns something of type T. The actual type T then can be defined by the function that's passed in.

Comment: This is awesome I didn't know that you could define a function signature like that without defining the function itself. Thanks

Comment: well.. what we defined there is a function parameter that is expected to be a function that takes no parameter and returns something. that's all. :)

Comment: Brill exactly what I needed